# In what way should SVDLIB be used?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, matrix, implementation, svd

I am trying to use SVDLIBC in my java project(Google app engine app). I have read an article that says there is SVDLIBJ but it is broken, not use it and etc. Is there good way to implement it and in addition to work on the cloud? I would be even better if you could give me   some helpful tips and documentation. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fast SVD algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081516/fast-svd-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the only SVD implementation in the world.  If this one doesn't work, I'd recommend that you find another one.  It's not hard to do: [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) has one.  I know there are others.  Dig in, find one, test it out with a simple problem with a known answer, and then go from there.