# Compute Gradient of overdefined Plane

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-regression, svd

I want to compute the **gradient** (direction and magnitude) of an overdefined plane (> 3 points), such as e.g. four x, y, z coordinates:

> [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]

[image]

My code for computing the gradient looks like this (using singular value decomposition from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747643/3d-linear-regression/55604956), modified):

```
import numpy as np
def regr(X):
    y = np.average(X, axis=0)
    Xm = X - y
    cov = (1./X.shape[0])*np.matmul(Xm.T,Xm)   # Covariance
    u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(cov)               # Singular Value Decomposition
    return u[:,1]
```

However as a result I get:

> [0, 1, 0]

which does not represent the gradient nor the normal vector. The result should look like this:

> [sqrt(2)/2, 0, -sqrt(2)/2]

Any ideas why I am getting a wrong vector?

Comment: Are you sure a `dtype` is being used that can hold floating point numbers? It's not just `int` values, right?

Comment: @RandomDavis I have just checked it, it can hold floating point numbers. It doesn't look like a numerical but a conceptual problem to me...

Comment: @blackst0ne your output result is normal to that surface. However, I am not sure what you mean by slope on a 2-D surface. Could you please elaborate on that so we can help better? Thank you.

Comment: @Ehsan thanks for your comment. Sorry for the spongy expression, I meant the gradient. And the result [0, 1, 0] is not the normal vector to the plane specified by the four points. However Joe could provide me some useful links.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [numpy.gradient](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) for that. Here is some [math background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_of_a_vector) how it works.

In short:

The directional derivative will be the dot product of the gradient with the (unit normalized) vector of the direction.

An easier solution is to use [numdifftools](https://pypi.org/project/numdifftools/), especially the convenience function [directionaldiff](https://numdifftools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/numdifftools.html#numdifftools.core.directionaldiff).
An example can be found [here](https://github.com/pbrod/numdifftools/blob/531911c0fe0955cb91e167df254b69d96d02e067/src/numdifftools/tests/test_nd_scipy.py#L59). And if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/pbrod/numdifftools/blob/3f099d4bb5fc13a65d3d8611eadffc797511b342/src/numdifftools/core.py#L493) you can see the relation to the math mentioned above.

Comment: I just read your links in more depth, and unfortunately they do not solve my problem. I have an overdefined plane (> 3 points), and that's why I tried the singular value decomposition. Your solution works fine for well defined planes, however not for overdefined ones (e.g. 4 points or 9 points).

Comment: You could fit your points to a plane equation and feed that into the function.